# How to render svg to pdf at a given physical (centimetres) size?

Tags: linux, pdf, svg

Suppose I have a svg image. Take this for example:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-1 -1 2 2" width="100" height="100">
        <polygon fill="green" points="1.0,0.0 6.123233995736766e-17,1.0 -1.0,1.2246467991473532e-16 -1.8369701987210297e-16,-1.0"></polygon>
        <polygon fill="blue" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.03" points="1.0,0.0 -0.4999999999999998,0.8660254037844387 -0.5000000000000004,-0.8660254037844384"></polygon>
</svg>
```

This renders as intended in my browser (Firefox):

[image]

(I say "renders correctly" but Firefox renders this as 200x200 pixels, not 100x100 as expected. Not the main question, but why did it get scaled? No, firefox is not zoomed. In Chromium it renders as 120x1020 pixels.)

I want to render this to a pdf such that it takes up exactly, say, 15cm x 15cm (with a margin of, say, 2cm).

Ideally this would render to the same result even if I change `width="100" height="100"` to something else -- i.e. the top left corner is at (2cm,2cm) on the physical page when printed, and the bottom right corner is (17cm,17cm) and this uses 100% of the svg image regardless of the svg's internal coordinate system.

How can I do this in on Linux cli?

Comment: I'm really looking for a command like `svg_to_pdf -i foo.svg -o foo.pdf --width=15cm --height=15cm --margin-left=2cm --margin-top=2cm` and note that the particular svg in the question is *just an example*

Comment: Looks the same size in Firefox and Chrome to me. What operating system are you using? Do you have. a mac with a retina display or some other hardware that might introduce a 2x magnification?

Answer (score 0):

When deciding an optimal programming path we look for the aims then the shortest efficient coding route.

Your aim is a module to produce a PDF like this from SVG via the console command line interface.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Which requires a PDF output file like:-

```
%PDF-1.4
%µ¶

1 0 obj <</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R>>
endobj
2 0 obj <</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[3 0 R]>>
endobj
3 0 obj <</Type/Page/Resources<</ExtGState<</G3 4 0 R/G4 5 0 R>>>>/MediaBox[0 0 539.04 539.04]/Contents 6 0 R/StructParents 0/Parent 2 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj <</ca 1/BM/Normal>>
endobj
5 0 obj <</CA 1/ca 1/LC 0/LJ 0/LW .03/ML 4/SA true/BM/Normal>>
endobj
6 0 obj <</Length 396>>
stream
q
.24 0 0 -.24 0 539 cm
239.17322 236.04822 1771.6536 1771.6536 re W* n
q
885.8268 0 0 885.8268 1125 1122 cm 0 .502 0 rg 0 .502 0 RG /G3 gs
1 0 m .000000000000000061232339 1 l -1 .00000000000000012246469 l -.00000000000000018369703 -1 l 1 0 l h f
1 0 m -.5 .86602547 l -.5 -.86602547 l 1 0 l h 0 0 1 rg f
1 0 0 rg 1 0 0 RG /G4 gs .03 w 4 M 1 0 m -.5 .86602547 l -.5 -.86602547 l 1 0 l h S
Q
Q

endstream
endobj

xref
0 7
0000000000 65536 f 
0000000016 00000 n 
0000000061 00000 n 
0000000112 00000 n 
0000000260 00000 n 
0000000295 00000 n 
0000000365 00000 n 

trailer
<</Size 7/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
808
%%EOF
```

So for that we need the simplest SVG to PDF converter that works cross platforms. The best universal candidate is, Edge/Chromium browser --headless --print-to-pdf from command line.

In Windows terms it will be MSEdge.exe for Chromium and also need %CD% to build in current folder
`Chromium --headless --print-to-pdf="%cd%\svg-out.pdf" "svg-in.htm"`

How to build SVG-in.htm is up to the users programming skills at writing a shell script that uses arguments and parameters. So here I am simply offering the method, but in  Windows it will be easy to write a batch script that takes commands and uses them in the correct variable locations as parameters for scaling etc.

svg-in.htm part 1 (a.txt) or add the variables via scripting.

```
<html><head><style>@media print{@page{margin:0; size:19cm 19cm;}body{margin0;}} 
svg {position:fixed;border:0;left:8.2cm;bottom:8.2cm;scale:calc(37.79527559*15/100);} 
</style></head><body style="margin: 0px;">
```

concatenate the SVG (in Windows will be `copy a.txt+b.svg svg-in.htm`)
and echo a file closure `echo ^</div^>^</body^>^</html^> >>svg-in.htm`

Thus as proof of concept on Windows a script would run like this

```
copy svg-in.txt+svg-in.svg svg-in.htm
echo ^</div^>^</body^>^</html^> >>svg-in.htm
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --headless --print-to-pdf="%cd%\svg-out.pdf" --no-pdf-header-footer --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw "%cd%\svg-in.htm"
timeout 3 
svg-out.pdf
```

[image]